# how can i trigger jenkins automatically ,when there is push in gitlab?

Tags: amazon-ec2, jenkins, gitlab, single-instance

Have configured jenkins & sonarqube on AWS Instance
***Have To do***
Want to trigger jenkins ,when there is push in gitlab

Jenkins detect push from gitlab & repo fetched is passed to sonarqube

Result of sonar should be shown in gitlab & issue mail is sent to concerned developer..

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are looking for is called Continuous Integration. There are official [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html)

Comment: Have configured in similar manner....But getting issue ,when i am getting push from gitlab.then It's not working.                                             Manually i can build my project in jenkins,at that time It's working fine

Comment: Sorry but `It's not working` isn't enough to say. Do you have any logs/messages?